# PHP: contact details error

Tags: php

I have text box for contact number.
if I enter mobile number 09234567819 it is inserting correctly.
but if I entered value like 040-22234323 a landline num with std code.it is giving value which is a negative number.
also I found that when I gathering value by $_GET['mob'] it is doing subtraction.

how to avoid hyphen to be worked as subtraction.

Comment: put your number in to inverted come like "123456-78910"

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: will like to see the code..

Comment: put your value inside single quote '040-22234323'

Comment: change type to 
   
         type="text" 

instead of 

         type="number"

Comment: Please, show us your code where you are inserting the number. Subtraction is something I see for the first time.

Comment: thanks yaar, It was a same case  Chintan Mathukiya said. I forgot to cover it with single inverted com in query .and because of that hyphen behaves as minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong data type. That value should be a string not a number.

In terms of HTML you could probably use the new "tel" field type. Like

```
<form>
  Telephone:
  <input type="tel" name="mob">
</form>
```